# Merge and commit in a single step with Mercurial

Tags: bash, merge, mercurial

On Mercurial if I want to merge a branch I always have to perform it in two steps:

```
hg merge my_branch
hg ci -m "I just merged my branch"
```

Is there a way in which I could do the same in a single command (having it aborted if conflicts are found)?

```
hg merge my_branch -ci "I merged my branch"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advise to execute the two at the same operation. The main reason is, during a merge conflict, you will need to resolve it before committing. So when the first operation fails, you are left out with a state that requires another commit anyway.

If you need to do this, to simplify the ideal case workflow, at least create a script to handle the conflictual case and revert back to the starting revision, so that the user can merge and commit normally. But using a simple alias will cause you more trouble than help you, in the end.

Comment: Although I like the simplicity of @eric approach, I think this is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Would 
`hg merge my_branch && hg ci -m "I just merged my branch"`
be acceptable or do you need to call `hg` only once?

`&&` executes the following command only if the first one returns successfully.

Edit:

If you need the command as an alias with arguments, this gets a bit more complicated, as aliases do not accept arguments. You can use a function and alias it though:

`branch_and_commit() { hg merge $1  && hg ci -m $2; } ; alias bac=branch_and_commit`

You can then call it like this:

`bac my_branch_id "this is the comment"`

Comment: I might, but if I would like to extend it in order to include the latest my_branch changeset id on the single line, I was looking for something like an alias.

Comment: and `bac` alias would be put on the hgrc file? is it valid to contain it there?

Comment: I would put it in .bashrc in order to have it available at any time and group it with my other aliases.

Comment: `bac` must be moved into *shell-alias* into .hgrc in order to have `hg bac ...`